# React Prettier auto fix of self-closing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint, prettier

React JSX

```
<Hello><Hello/>
```

to

```
<Hello/>
```

How can I fix code with prettier when I save code on VS code?
Which setting should I edit?

Comment: You need to setup prettier with eslint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `eslint-plugin-react`.
For reference please check below link

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I can't fix code when code is saved.
Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

If you  are using the Prettier plugin in VS Code, do this:

- Open the user settings - CTRL + ,
- Search "Format on Save" and turn it on

This will use the formatter, in this case prettier, to format your code whenever you save.

This has nothing to do with Eslint plugin as other people are saying.

Comment: Do you have the Prettier plugin installed? I doubled checked it and that is the setting that turns on formatting when you save. Try pressing CTRL + S to see if that works (If you are relying on auto-save)